# Query returning wrong result, one row is expected but getting ALL

Tags: mysql, sql

My statement below is returning all the results of the table instead of only with matching n1. I have attached the screenshot of the result. What I am expecting is just the first row. Can someone help me understand what is taking place here please?
[Result of the Query attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWIzw.jpg)

```
Create View Proj_Display AS
select * from Proj_d
Where "n" in (Select Student from proj_d);
```

Comment: We don't have enough information.

Comment: Apologies, it is "n1" above and not "n"

Comment: Do you want `WHERE student in (SELECT logged from proj_d)`?  That would return only the first row, but your query is unclear.

Comment: Do you mean Select * from Proj_d Where Student = "n1" or something more complicated?

Comment: So the idea is that I just want that row returned which matches with my the value I manually select i.e. "n1" / "n2" etc

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to them...)

Comment: If that's all you want then just `WHERE student = 'n1'`.  The subquery is over complicating it.  Usually you'll use a subquery where you *don't* want to manually feed the value in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Create View Proj_Display AS
select * from Proj_d
Where "n1" in (Select Student from proj_d);
```

This query you have now checks whether value "n1" exists in table proj_d. Which is always true.
So I guess you want something like this:

```
Create View Proj_Display AS
select * from Proj_d
Where Student  in (Select Student from proj_d WHERE Student = 'n1');
```

But you could do this right away without using a subquery:

```
Create View Proj_Display AS
select * from Proj_d
Where Student  = 'n1'
```

But probably you need to give more information what you want exactly

Comment: Why would this be a view? Why not just a query?

Comment: Thanks for the replies upto now. I am trying to understand the difference between EXISTS and IN, My wrong understanding upto now was that IN will just return one row and EXISTS will return true. I created this scenario to polish my understanding that if a student logs in then only sees its own row and I was going to develop it further that if a teacher logs in then can see the whole table. So I was thinking of adding - .......OR EXISTS (Select * from teacher where teacher = 't1'. @HLGEM @ Johan